# Can't backup database when LOG_BACKUP file is full

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

The problem that I encounter, is that the LOG_BACKUP file of one of my databases is full. This is a SQL Server 2012 environemnt. The problem occurs because there is a limited space allocated for the log file. The space on the disk itself is sufficient to do a backup. Normally on test systems I would set the recovery mode from FULL to SIMPLE, do a shrink file, and set it back to FULL.

However, I am now working on another system and I would like to preserve the backup chain. So the next thing I try is to increase the allocated space for the log file. This does not work because of the 9002 message (LOG_BACKUP full). Also doing a full backup of the database does not work, with the same message.

As far as I can find, these are the options to clear your LOG_BACKUP file. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you don't have space on the drive, you need to increase the space and then backup the log. You don't have to back up the log to the same place the `ldf` resides though. Worse case, increase the log file size, and then back it up. Then, start backing up your logs more frequently and only keep the logs since your last good full backup, or what ever you are comfortable wtih to meet your RPT and RTO so that you don't fill up the drive again. But drive space should be determined by your RPO and RTO needs, that is what is needed to meet those, not the other way around.

Comment: I have enough space on my disk at the moment, but I still get the message of the LOG_BACKUP being full when doing a manual full backup.

Comment: full backup of the log, or of the database? You need to backup the log explicitly. If you have full backup, then you can back it up to a NUL device. `BACKUP LOG dbname TO DISK = 'NUL:';`

Comment: @scsimon, thank you. Mistake on my part that I thought that a full backup would be required to clear the log file. I have done a backup of the transaction log and now it works again.

Comment: No worries at all, glad you are all sorted out.